# Pydantic v2 make some fields optional using a decorator function

Tags: python, pydantic

Pydantic version 1 allowed to use a decorator function like this one on classes to make certain fields optional on demand:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
import inspect


def optional(*fields):
    def dec(_cls):
        for field in fields:
            _cls.__fields__[field].required = False
        return _cls

    if fields and inspect.isclass(fields[0]) and issubclass(fields[0], BaseModel):
        cls = fields[0]
        fields = cls.__fields__
        return dec(cls)
    return dec


class Book(BaseModel):
    author: str
    available: bool
    isbn: str


@optional
class BookUpdate(Book):
    pass


@optional('val1', 'val2')
class Model(BaseModel):
    val1: str
    val2: str
    captcha: str
```

This code snippet worked even for nested classes with multiple inheritance levels.

How to use pydantic version >2 to implement a similar functionality, even if the mentioned attribute is inherited. Furthermore metadata should be retained (e.g. when I define a pydantic Field to populate my Dataclasses.

The following code works by making all fields optional (instead of only the decorated ones) and also does not retain metadata added to fields. (Field(title='test'))

```
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import create_model

def optional(*fields):
    def dec(cls):
        fields_dict = {}
        for field in fields:
            field_info = cls.__annotations__.get(field)
            if field_info is not None:
                fields_dict[field] = (Optional[field_info], None)
        OptionalModel = create_model(cls.__name__, **fields_dict)
        OptionalModel.__module__ = cls.__module__

        return OptionalModel

    if fields and inspect.isclass(fields[0]) and issubclass(fields[0], BaseModel):
        cls = fields[0]
        fields = cls.__annotations__
        return dec(cls)

    return dec
```

Answer (score 0):

In Pydantic version 1, the optional decorator worked by modifying the required attribute of specified fields in the class. However, in Pydantic version 2 and above, the internal structure has changed, and modifying attributes directly like that might not be feasible.

To achieve a similar functionality in Pydantic version 2, you can use a custom validator to mark certain fields as optional. Also, to retain metadata, you can use the **annotations** attribute of the class to access the type information.

```
from typing import Optional, Type
from pydantic import BaseModel, create_model, validator, Field
import inspect


def optional(*fields):
    def dec(cls):
        class OptionalModel(cls):
            class Config:
                extra = "allow"

        for field in fields:
            OptionalModel.__annotations__[field] = Optional[cls.__annotations__.get(field, str)]
            OptionalModel.__config__.extra_fields[field].default = None

        return OptionalModel

    if fields and inspect.isclass(fields[0]) and issubclass(fields[0], BaseModel):
        cls = fields[0]
        fields = cls.__annotations__
        return dec(cls)

    return dec


class Book(BaseModel):
    author: str
    available: bool
    isbn: str


@optional
class BookUpdate(Book):
    pass


@optional('val1', 'val2')
class Model(BaseModel):
    val1: str
    val2: str
    captcha: str

    class Config:
        fields = {'val1': Field(title='test'), 'val2': Field(title='test2')}

# Example usage
data = {
    'author': 'John Doe',
    'available': True,
    'isbn': '1234567890',
    'val1': 'value1',
    'val2': 'value2',
    'captcha': 'abcd1234',
}

book_update = BookUpdate(**data)
model_instance = Model(**data)

print(book_update)
print(model_instance)
```

As you can see here, the optional decorator creates a new class (OptionalModel) that inherits from the original class (cls). It then adds the specified fields as optional with the help of the Optional type. The validator is used to set the default value of optional fields to None. The Config class is used to retain metadata, and it includes the definition of extra fields with their titles.